Asymptotic distribution of repetitions in binary sequence
Let $N$ be a fixed positive integer.
Let $b_1,\dots,b_M$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoullay random variables with $p=\frac12$. So $P(b_i=0)=\frac12=P(b_i=1)$ for all $i$. Now let $X$ be the amount of subsequences consisting of $N$ consecutive zeroes. This means that $b_i,\dots,b_{i+N-1}$ are all zero.
Now I would like to know the distribution of $X$, for $M>>N$. Specifically: what are the expectation value and standard deviation of $X$? I wanted to apply the central limit theorem, but that seems tricky in this case. For $N=1$ it is simple: then we can actually apply the central limit theorem, and we get expected value $\frac{M}{2}$ and standard deviation $\frac12\sqrt M$.

Are you concerned with counting only the $longest$ runs? So when you have, say, a sub-sequence $n$ consecutive zeros, do you also count the sub-sequences consisting of $n-1, n-2, \ldots$ zeros, i.e. the sub-sequences of that sub-sequence?

Nope, I fix N in the beginning. So a subquestion is for example [for N=2]: what is the distribution of the amount of substrings 00?

So in a substring 000, you will count 2 occurences of 00?

yes, exactly and that overlap is what makes it hard

I think I found the solution! What do you think?

Looks okay. But you were asking for the distribution...

I thought it would be approximately a normal distribution for large M

but your $X_i$ are not independent.

good point, then this is a conjecture

There are generalizations of the Central Limit Theorem that apply to weakly dependent sequences of random variables, see e.g. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-3/The-central-limit-theorem-for-dependent-random-variables/10.1215/S0012-7094-48-01568-3.short

I think I've found a way to make them independent, using a slightly different but still elementary construction. I'm not a 100% sure, but let's see.
So, first of all, I would like to think of the string as being cut into different sections by the 1s. For $k$ (your N) given, define the RV $X$ which counts the number of occurrences of length-$k$ sub-strings in the next 0-run. For a 0-run of length $n$, there are $n-k+1$ such sub-strings. For convenience let $j=k-1$. Obviously if $n\leq j$ there will be no such sub-strings.
We can therefore calculate the expected number of length-$k$ sub-strings in the next 0-run as:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]= S =\sum_{i=j}^{\infty} (i-j)p^i$$.
This series obviously converges, is dominated by $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ip^i$, which converges so long as |p| < 1. We can calculate this by repeatedly applying where we 'extract' the geometric series from $S$ (I'll spare you the details). This will yield:
$$(\frac{1}{1-p} - 1)\sum_{i=k}^{2k-1} p^i + p^{2k-1}S = S$$
or
$$S = \frac{p^{2k-1}+p}{1-p}\sum_{i=k}^{2k-1} p^i$$.
We can now use this to determine the expected number of $k$-length sub-string occurrences in the full string. Each sub-string is sandwiched between exactly 2 1s. For $M$ very large we expect $\frac{M}{2}$ 1s. So
$$\sum S_i = \frac{SM}{2}$$
We can plug some values into the above formula to check that it matches our expectations.

$k$=1: $S=1$, so $\sum S_i = \frac{M}{2}$, which is the expected result.
$k$=2: $S=\frac{24}{56}$ and so we expect $S=\frac{24M}{112}$ sub-strings of length 2, which is around 0.25M.

Variances can be calculated from the second moment as:
$$\mathbb{Var}][X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - S^2 = p^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2p^n= \frac{p^k(p^2+p)}{(1+p)^3} - S^2$$

Hi there, thanks for your answer! I guess that $p=\frac12$ in the case of my question? Also, what exactly is $S_i$?

That's slightly sloppy notation. The $i$ are supposed to index the individual 0-runs, each with expectation $S$.

Ok, so S is the expected number of length-k substrings in $S_i$

How do you get to the variance calculation?

No. $S_i$ is the expected number of $k$-length sub-strings in the $i$-th run. This is just the same for all $i$, namely $S$. The second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{i=j}^{\infty} (i-j)^2p^i$. You can do the calculation from there. Actually, what I'm showing might be just the second moment. Will have to check that.

It is the second moment, sorry. This is $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{i=j}^{\infty} (i-j)^2p^i$. You can do the calculation from there. So, for example for $k=2$ that will be something like ($\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2^2}{8}+ \frac{3^2}{16} + \ldots)$. You can factor out $p^k$ here. The second step is just a well-known equality. But take care that this actually the second moment. So you would have to subtract $\mathbb{E}[X]^2$.

I think this is right. The reason that it doesn't come out at exactly $p^k$ as one might naively expect as that we lose all the 0-runs smaller than $k$. For $k=2$ for instance, whenever we see a the sub-string 101, we don't count the 0. And we'll see quite a bunch of those.

Its slightly different from my result, so I guess one of us made a calculation error... but its only up to a constant factor so not that bad

Hmm. What is that factor?

For p=0.5 I get expectation value $2^{-k}M$, as opposed to your $(1+0.5^{2k-2}))(0.5^{k-1}-0.5^{2k-1})\frac M2$.

We can solve this question using the concepts of linearity of expectation value, variance, and covariance.
For $i=1,2,\dots,M-N+1$, let $X_i$ be the random variable that is $1$ is $b_i=\dots=b_{i+N-1}=0$ and that is $0$ otherwise. Now $X=\sum_i X_i$. For all $i$, the expectation value of $X_i$ is $2^{-N}$, so the expectation value of $X$ is $2^{-N}(M-N+1)$. For large $M$ this is approximately $2^{-N}M$.
When $|i-j|\geq N$, we have $cov(X_i,X_j)=0$. Now let $j=i+\Delta$ with $\Delta\in\{1,2,\dots,N-1\}$. Then $cov(X_i,X_j)=E[X_iX_j]-E[X_i]E[X_j]=2^{-N-\Delta}-2^{-2N}$.
We also have $Var(X_i)=2^{-N}(1-2^{-N})$ for all $i$. Now we have $$Var(X)=\sum_i  Var(X_i)+2\sum_{i<j}cov(X_i,X_j)=(M-N+1)(2^{-N}-2^{-2N})\\+2\cdot \sum_{i<j<i+N}[2^{-N-(j-i)}-2^{-2N}].$$ For $M$ large this is approximately $$M(2^{-N}-2^{-2N})+2M\sum_{\Delta=1}^{N-1} [2^{-N-\Delta}-2^{-2N}]\\=M(2^{-N}-2^{-2N}+2^{-N+1}-2^{-2N+2}-2(N-1)2^{-2N})=M(3\cdot2^{-N}-(2N+3)2^{-2N}).$$
Therefore the standard deviation of $X$ is $\sqrt{M(3\cdot2^{-N}-(2N+3)2^{-2N})}$ for large $M$.
For small values of $N$, we get the following standard deviations:
$$N=1 \quad  \sigma = 0.5\sqrt M$$
$$N=2 \quad  \sigma = 0.56\sqrt M$$
$$N=3 \quad  \sigma = 0.48 \sqrt M$$
$$N=4 \quad \sigma =  0.38 \sqrt M$$
$$N=5 \quad \sigma =  0.28 \sqrt M$$
